# Calculus Optimization Problem

Tags: calculus

A piece of wire $12$ m long is cut into two pieces. One piece is bent into a square and the other is bent into an equilateral triangle.

How much wire should be used for the square in order to minimize the total area?

I got $\frac{12}{(1+\pi/4)}$ as my answer, but apparently that's wrong... I've been stuck on this problem for hours, can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The total area you want to minimize is $$\underbrace{x^2}_{\text{square with side $x$}}+\underbrace{\frac{\left(\frac{12-x}{3}\right)^2\sqrt{3}}{4}}_{\text{equilateral triangle with side $\frac{12-x}{3}$}}$$

---

The above equation can be written as $$x^2+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{36}(144-24x+x^2) \implies \frac{36+\sqrt3}{36}x^2-\frac{2\sqrt3}{3}x+4\sqrt3$$ with first derivative $$\frac{36+\sqrt3}{18}x-\frac{2\sqrt3}{3}$$ which yields (when set equal to $0$) $$x=\frac{12\sqrt3}{36 +\sqrt3}=\frac{12}{12\sqrt3+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt3+\frac{1}{12}}$$ The second derivative is positive, so this is indeed a minimum.

Comment: Right, but I keep getting 12/(1+pi/4)....

Comment: @user136146 where does pi come from...?

Comment: @user136146 You aren't doing a related problem with a polygon and a circle, are you?  This posted problem will not have any factor of $ \ \pi \ $ in the areas of the square and the triangle...